# How do I filter a table in Excel based on a column of values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a very large table in Excel which represents a call log. The log has the results made to a few thousand numbers.

I'd like to filter this table to only show me the results from a subset of these numbers. The subset, however, is extremely large (over 1,000), so I cannot simply click use the Autofilter feature and click the checkbox for each one, because that would take forever.

How do I ask Excel to only show me those values where the telephone number appears in a different column?

Right now, the table is columns A-G, and the subset is in Column N, but I can put the subset on a separate sheet if that's easier.

Comment: A simple solution would be to use a helper column next to your table.  In that, lookup the record's number in the column N list and store a result like 1 if found or blank or zero if not.  Then filter on that.

Comment: Thanks! not sure why i didn't think of that.

Comment: So you have a log. I suppose you import this log and i'ts not aligning properly, hence the phone numbers in the wrong column? Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use a helper column next to your table. In that, lookup the record's number in the column N list and store a result like 1 if found or blank or zero if not. Then filter on that. – fixer1234 5 mins ago